Unable to start sshd and dbus service in CentOS9
I am seeing the below issues in CentOS 9 running on a container. Previous versions such as centos-7/8 works fine.
sshd[131]: fatal: chroot("/usr/share/empty.sshd"): Operation not permitted [preauth]

systemd[92]: dbus-broker.service: Failed to set up mount namespacing: Operation not permitted
systemd[92]: dbus-broker.service: Failed at step NAMESPACE spawning /usr/bin/dbus-broker-launch: Operation not permitted

systemctl list-units --failed
  UNIT                   LOAD   ACTIVE SUB    DESCRIPTION
● dbus-broker.service    loaded failed failed D-Bus System Message Bus
● dnf-makecache.service  loaded failed failed dnf makecache
● rsyslog.service        loaded failed failed System Logging Service
● systemd-logind.service loaded failed failed User Login Management
● dbus.socket            loaded failed failed D-Bus System Message Bus Socket

SELinux is disabled.

$getenforce
Disabled

Here are the versions of systemctl and dbus-broker:

$systemctl --version
systemd 252 (252-38.el9)
+PAM +AUDIT +SELINUX -APPARMOR +IMA +SMACK +SECCOMP +GCRYPT +GNUTLS +OPENSSL +ACL +BLKID +CURL +ELFUTILS -FIDO2 +IDN2 -IDN -IPTC +KMOD +LIBCRYPTSETUP +LIBFDISK +PCRE2 -PWQUALITY +P11KIT -QRENCODE +TPM2 +BZIP2 +LZ4 +XZ +ZLIB +ZSTD -BPF_FRAMEWORK +XKBCOMMON +UTMP +SYSVINIT default-hierarchy=unified

$dbus-broker --version
dbus-broker 28


wait, why is SELinux disabled? That feels like it points to you "solving" (it's practically never the right solution to disable SELinux) another problem, which might be intimately related to this.
